Laravel 11 - Calling a Procedure in a Model
I'm new to laravel and try to make some simple test websites to get better.
I try to call a public procedure I've made in a model. The Idea is to put all the SQL Selects out of the code in the website.I've tried a lot and read a lot about it but what can I say. I'm lost at the moment.
My Model :
class Terroir extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'type',
        'terroir_id',
    ];

    public function Countries() {
        $countrys= Terroir::select(['name','id'])
        ->where ('type',1)
        ->wherenull('terroir_id')
        ->orderby('name','ASC')
        ->get();

        return($countrys);
    }
}

If I try to call it like that inside a PHP Tag :
$countrys=App\Models\Terroir::with('Countries');
But it didn't reach the model.
This works inside the PHP-Code :
$countrys = App\Models\Terroir::select(['name','id'])
                            ->where ('type',1) 
                            ->wherenull ('terroir_id') 
                            ->orderby('name','ASC')
                            ->get();

So I hope I'm not totaly wrong to try to call a procedure inside the Model.
I think I need help how to call this simple procedure correctly (If it is possible anyway).
Best regards, Stephan

with is used to load model relations

Ah ok used it in another model with a relation. Now this seems to work :
$countrys=App\Models\Terroir::Countries()->get();
And defined a static function . Hope this is correct, thx for the tip !

Well, for those who are new to Eloquent (Laravel orm), I always recommend distinguishing the differences between query builder, collection, and model instance.
Query builder:
As the name says, you can make queries with it, create it with the DB:: facade, or use models as well.
Example:
App\Models\Terroir::select(['name','id'])
    ->where ('type',1) 
    ->wherenull ('terroir_id') 
    ->orderby('name','ASC');

You need to know this is query builder and as long as you keep chaining the query builder methods like where() it will stay a query builder. There are some methods you can call on query builder faze for example a method with a prefix of scope or relationships can be put into with() for eager loading. But for a custom method or procedure you can't call it because you are not dealing with a single model instance it's query builder.
Collection:
This is class like arrays for Laravel that provide extra features. If you chain the ->get() method to query builder by default you will get a collection of models. Then you can iterate throw them. There are other methods to fetch the query and convert it to collection as well.
Model instance:
This is class like arrays for Laravel that provides extra features. If you chain the ->first() method to query builder by default you will get a model instance. There are other methods to fetch the query and convert it to the model instance as well.
So for the calling procedure because you dealing with a model instance first you need to get the model instance then you can call the method.
And because of this, the first code you wrote doesn't make sense because first, you need to get a random model,and  then call the method. The second code if it's working then I think its ok to use. But solutions for the first code:

Use a static procedure. (Im not quite fond of it)
Use Laravel standards like local-scopes https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Code for the first solution
class Terroir extends Model {
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'type',
    'terroir_id',
];

public static function countries() {
    return Terroir::select(['name','id'])
    ->where ('type',1)
    ->wherenull('terroir_id')
    ->orderby('name','ASC')
    ->get();
}}

Then you can call it like this:
$countrys = App\Models\Terroir::countries();

I recommend reading more about these in Laravel docs.

Thx a will do ! This was just a test how to get some data inside a php tag. And the main Problem eas, how to call this procedure inside the model. I got so much different errors (I was hours inside google to see what these errors mean). Of course the target is to use laravel standards from the scratch, so I will now dive deeper into scopes and what they will do. Thx a lot ! I'm just starting :-)

Try using Local Scopes. Local Scopes
class Terroir extends Model{

    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'type',
        'terroir_id',
    ];

    public function scopeIsCountry(Builder $query): void {
         $query->where('type',1)
        ->wherenull('terroir_id');
    }
}

Controller
class TerroirController extends Controller{

    public function index()
    {
       
        $countries = App\Models\Terroir::isCountry()
            ->get();
    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $searchTerm = $request->input('q');
        $countries = App\Models\Terroir::query()
            ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
            ->isCountry()
            ->get();
        return $countries;
    }
}

